# Pandas- group string values

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"booking": ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
               "city": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
               "orders": [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],})
```

Need to group values to see: what is the sum of orders for each city, I think the best way is to create new DataFrame with two columns:

1. list of cities
2. list with SUM of order to each city

If with 2nd point is clear:

```
new_df1=df.groupby(['booking', 'city'])['orders'].apply(sum).groupby(level=0).apply(list)
print(new_df1)
```

But with 1st point is not clear, need to get list of unique cities for each booking, like:

```
needed_df = pd.DataFrame({"booking": ['A', 'B', 'C'],
               "city_list": [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]})
```

Comment: expected output is needed_df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `unique`

```
out = df.groupby('booking')['city'].agg(pd.unique).reset_index()
Out[7]: 
  booking       city
0       A  [a, b, c]
1       B     [a, b]
2       C  [c, d, e]
```

Comment: where is the sum by the city